# Is there a legendary biography of Avalokitesvara/Kwan-Yin/Chenrezig?

Tags: reference-request, mahayana, kwan-yin

I've googled this, but can't find it. I know there is a tradition of writing legendary/mythological/fictional biographies (hagiographies) of monks in the Chinese tradition.

Just a few days ago was the celebration of Kwan Yin's going forth day, but for the life of me, I can't find any other accounts of Kwan Yin's life as a monk or nun.

Answer (score 1):

Also known as [Chenrezig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalokite%C5%9Bvara) in the Tibetan tradition, Avalokiteśvara is widely known through most Buddhist traditions.

> According to legend, Chenrezig made a a vow that he would not rest
> until he had liberated all the beings in all the realms of suffering.
> After working diligently at this task for a very long time, he looked
> out and  realized the immense number of miserable beings yet to be
> saved. Seeing this, he became despondent and his head split into
> thousands of pieces. Amitabha Buddha put the pieces back together as a
> body with very many arms and many heads, so that Chenrezig could work
> with myriad beings all at the same time. Sometimes Chenrezig is
> visualized with eleven heads, and a thousand arms fanned out around
> him.

He has a total of 33 forms, including the wrathful form of [Mahakala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81k%C4%81la)
He is also considered to be the "parent" of [Tara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara_(Buddhism))

> In Tibetan Buddhism, Tara came into existence from a single tear shed
> by Avalokiteśvara. When the tear fell to the ground it created a lake,
> and a lotus opening in the lake revealed Tara. In another version of
> this story, Tara emerges from the heart of Avalokiteśvara. In either
> version, it is Avalokiteśvara's outpouring of compassion which
> manifests Tara as a being

He is mentioned in the following sutras :

> Lotus Sutra
>
> Kāraṇḍavyūhasūtra
>
> Heart Sutra
>
> Nīlakaṇṭha Dhāraṇī Sutra
>
> Eleven-Faced Avalokitesvara Heart Dharani Sutra
>
> Cundī Dhāraṇī Sūtra

Pictured below Avalokitesvara in his 1000 armed form and as Mahakala, and Tara

[image]
[image]
[image]